# How to run the same block of python on multiple machines

Tags: python, environment, remote-server

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is add a decorator to a python function that would automatically run that function on a remote machine. To clarify with a use case, let's say I have a function that I know will take `8g` of RAM, my machine only has 4, and I want to automatically run that function on a remote machine with more RAM (to clarify, this is a toy example, and just running the code on my AWS instance is not an option)

What I'm imagining is something along these lines:

```
@remote
def big_func(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do something

def remote(func):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = requests.post('<remote_ip>', data={'func': func}) # for example
        return resp.content # result
    return func
```

and I'm having trouble devising a way to "send" the function over to another computer while ensuring that it remains executable. I thought about using `pickle`'s, but sadly `pickle` files assume that you will be running under the same environment.

I have control over any pre-installed packages on the remote machine, and I can send additional information over with the POST request, but that's about it.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with Celery. It provides an `@job` decorator; you can then run workers on multiple machines.